# Why does my animation render in black?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

My animation keeps rendering in black, how do I fix it?: [image]

Here's the file if you want to edit it. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38570

Comment: You need a lamp for this

Answer (score 1):

You need a lamp in your scene. This can be done with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and click on lamp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need include a light.

[image]